# Windows Phone Progress Bar in Listbox shows random values

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, progress-bar

In my windows phone 8.1 application I have code like in ListBox template;

```
<StackPanel>
<ProgressBar x:Name="DownloadProgressBar" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Value="25"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
</ProgressBar>
</StackPanel>
```

Even if I am setting static values into control, when page loaded progress bars showing some arbitrary values (progress value). I have around 10 items in the list and all progress bars are showing some another values.

I am expecting that all progress bars should show 25%.

What's wrong in this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your logic, put a

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
    <!-- rest of your template -->
</Border>
```

and you will realize what is going on.

You will see that each Item has a different width, thus making your Progress bar stretch to different width values.

To fix this you need to edit `<ListBox>` ItemContainerStyle's Style.

Comment: Omg, you are totally right! it takes up the space of content width. 
Uh.. I can go to sleep now, was pulling my hair because of this. Thanks!

Comment: @Teomanshipahi no problem, made the same mistake myself :) good night.